# Add Information to Database without loosing old in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to add some data to a row called "data".

At the moment I am using the Update command but this is overwriting the existing data. I need to hold the existing data and just add the new one to it.

Comment: Please provide example data before and after this operation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$model::$db->insert('UPDATE table SET data = CONCAT(data, "' . $link . '") WHERE id = "'. $id . '"');
```

It will concat your data with existing data